# Is there a way to convert from Func<T, string> to Func<dynamic, string>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a `Func<T, string>` that I want converted to `Func<dynamic, string>`. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have a `Func<T, string>` then that func expects a value of type `T`.  You can certainly wrap a `Func<dynamic, string>` around it, but it will fail at runtime if the `dynamic` argument is not an instance of `T`.  And without `Func<T, string>` being an expression tree, there's no way to decompose it and re-assemble it with a dynamic argument instead.

Comment: Good answers and comments from everyone. The answer is simple as you see below and I was just to tired to see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go.  Just need to decide what you want to do when your dynamic value isn't of type `T`:

```
public Func<dynamic, string> ConvertToDynamicFunc<T>(Func<T, string> typedFunc)
{
    Func<dynamic, string> dynamicFunc = (input) =>
    {
        if (input is T)
            return typedFunc((T)input);

        return null; //or throw?
    };

    return dynamicFunc;
}

Func<int, string> typedFunc = (input) => input.ToString();
Func<dynamic, string> dynamicFunc = ConvertToDynamicFunc(typedFunc);
System.Console.WriteLine(dynamicFunc(10));//outputs "10";
System.Console.WriteLine(dynamicFunc(10.5));//outputs null since a double isn't an int (type T) or throw if you prefer;
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
Func<T, string> input = ...
Func<dynamic, string> output = x => input(x);
```

Of course, if you execute the delegate with an incompatible type, you'll get a `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: Sure, but will fail at runtime if the input into `output` is not `T`.  (even if the dynamic argument duck-typed the same members)  Though admittedly this is the best you can do.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Sure, but if you're willing to use dynamic in the first place, you've obviously evaluated the risk and gone ahead anyway.

Comment: What I mean is if you write a dynamic-based implementation first, such as `Func<dynamic, string> foo = x => x.SomeMethod();` and then compare that with what you get when using your technique, there is a significant difference in effect where your technique is dramatically less powerful than the original.  Just thought that was worth mentioning.